# How to execute multiple .write() commands?

Tags: node.js

I have here my code in node JS, how can i execute multiple .write() commands? the output of this code will create a test.xls file, when i open that file it only displays the first writeStream.write which is the header("Sl No"+"\t"+" Age"+"\t"+"Name"+"\n") and I want all of them (header, row1, row2) to execute all together and display all of them on the test.xls file

```js
exports.post = function(req, res){

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("test.xls");
var header="Sl No"+"\t"+" Age"+"\t"+"Name"+"\n";
var row1 = "0"+"\t"+" 21"+"\t"+"Rob"+"\n";
var row2 = "1"+"\t"+" 22"+"\t"+"bob"+"\n";

writeStream.write(header);
writeStream.write(row1);
writeStream.write(row2);
writeStream.close();
  
};
```

Comment: Why are you breaking out `"\t"` and `"\n"` separately?  You can just embed all that in one string `var header = "Sl No\tAge\tName\n";`.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't all there in the file?  How are you looking at the file?  Also, this is doing nothing `['header', 'row1', 'row2'].join('\t')`.  Why is it there?

Comment: oh okay sorry. im just making my code organized

Comment: Yes i know that join command wont do anything, i just delete that

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the resulting file with a text editor and see what is actually in the file.

Comment: I'd also suggest you put an error handler on the write stream so you can see any errors that might be occurring.  `writeStream.on('error', err => console.log(err));`.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing them all at once is a quick fix :

```
writeStream.write(header + '\n' + row1 + '\n' + row2);
writeStream.close();
```

Using `.end` vs `.close` because node is async. From my understanding `end` waits for all writeable chunks to finish and `close` terminates the stream.

```
writeStream.write(header);
writeStream.write(row1);
writeStream.write(row2);
writeStream.end();
```

> ```
> close and error events are emitted when a stream ends due to failure (e.g. stream.destroy())
> end is emitted when a readable stream has no more data
> ```

[source](https://maxogden.com/node-streams.html)

Comment: This is more of a work-around, not really an explanation to why the OP was having the problem in their code.